# Handling Login of SAAS application end users

Tags: database, saas

I am designing a SAAS application with multi-tenant database  per-user-per-database with unique sub-domain of subscribed users. The question arises when subscribed user of saas application add more users to their dashboard or product so how to handle their login from our main application page because their database entry will only be in their Administrator database. Or should i use one global database for all users to handle logins ?

I am looking for any valuable suggestion , i am a newbie and has just started working on SAAS application

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution for this is to use a global database (called metadata database) where you save all the tenants of your application. A easy example of users table could be something like this;

```
tenants
- id
- subdomain
- db_host
- db_name
- db_user 
- db_password
```

Then when a user try to access to your application you can check in this table, the database name and credentials for use their own database.

I hope i have been able to help you